# Objective-C: why my NSString is not retaining its value?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

The problem lies within the 'initWithCoder' method.  When I want to retrieve "Coins_Key" from where I saved it by calling the 'saveData' method in my 'main' class and I pass in the key "self.keyName," the value of keyName is 0.

```
//Class coins.h
@property (retain) NSString* keyName;
@property (retain) NSString* keyValue;

//Class coins.m
@synthesize keyName;
-(void) saveData:(NSString *)number: (NSString *)keyID 
{
    self.keyName = keyID;
    self.keyValue = number;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
     NSLog(@"Encoded keyName: %@", keyName);
    [encoder encodeObject:keyValue forKey:keyName];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self.keyValue = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:self.keyName];
    NSLog(@"Decoded Coins: %@", self.keyValue);
    return self;
}

//Class main
[Coins *coin3 = [[Coins alloc] init];
[coin3 saveData:@"6" :@"Coins_Key"];        
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:coin3];
coin3 = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: The value 'keyName' is correct inside 'encodeWithCoder', but for 'initWithCoder' it is nil

Answer (score 1):

You're not quite grasping the encoder/decoder workflow.

Using the `encodeObjectForKey:` and `decodeObjectForKey:` methods properly, you should be passing as an argument the **key** that should be used to store the value. **This key must remain constant.**

You should also not require callers to provide the key your `Coin` object uses to store data. Take this simple example as a more correct/efficient method (assuming I understand the purpose of your class):

// Class Coins.h

```
@property (assign) int numberOfCoins;
```

// Class Coins.m

```
#define NUM_COINS_KEY @"NUM_COINS_KEY"

@synthesize numberOfCoins;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) { // Use [super initWithCoder:decoder] here if your superclass supports it
        self.numberOfCoins = [decoder decodeIntForKey:NUM_COINS_KEY];
        NSLog(@"Decoded Coins: %d", self.numberOfCoins);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
     NSLog(@"Encoded keyName: %@", keyName);
    [encoder encodeInt:self.numberOfCoins forKey:NUM_COINS_KEY];
}
```

// Class main

```
Coins *coin = [[Coins alloc] init];
coin.numberOfCoins = 6;
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:coin];
[coin release]; // If you're just playing around, this is probably overkill, but a good habit
coin = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: You said that it should not require callers to provide the key, but is it possible to call the decoder with a key in mind and only pull that one out? My purpose for this is so that whenever I need, say 'NUM_COINS_KEY' and not anything else that may be in there, can I somehow give it the *exact* key that I want by calling a method from main, such as getInt("NUM_COINS_KEY"), which will return the number value of coins. Thanks for your response btw!

Comment: The NSCoding protocol, and the **initWithCoder/encodeWithCoder** methods should only be used when serializing data. (Usually to disk or over a network connection.) I think what you're looking for is a key-based storage mechanism that you can use during the execution of your application. This is commonly called a Map or Dictionary. The Objective-C equivalent is an NSMutableDictionary. There's an example here: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/03/20/nsmutabledictionary-example-iphone-app-development-basics-in-objective-c/